# OpenGL2 2D textures showing up black, but working on OpenGL2 ES

Tags: opengl

I have some OpenGL code that works on OpenGL 2 ES (iOS) but when the code runs on OpenGL 2 (OS X), my textures come out black (or some other color if I force the color in the shader).  The geo is correct, I'm just getting black pixels.

Here are my shaders:  They are compiling without errors.

```
static const char *shader_source[2][2] =
{
{ NULL, NULL },

{
    /* Vertex shader */
    "uniform mat4 modelViewProj;\n"
    "uniform mat4 textureMatrix;\n"
    "attribute vec4 position;\n"
    "attribute vec2 texcoord;\n"
    "varying vec2 varyingUV;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_Position = modelViewProj * vec4( position.xyz, 1 );\n"
    "   varyingUV = (textureMatrix * vec4( texcoord.xy, 0, 1 )).xy;\n"
    "}\n",
    /* Fragment shader */
#ifdef PLATFORM_IOS
    "uniform lowp vec4 color;\n"
    "uniform sampler2D colorMap;\n"
    "varying lowp vec2 varyingUV;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   lowp vec4 texColor = texture2D( colorMap, varyingUV );\n"
    "   gl_FragColor = color * texColor;\n"
    "}"
#endif
#ifdef PLATFORM_OSX
    "uniform vec4 color;\n"
    "uniform sampler2D colorMap;\n"
    "varying vec2 varyingUV;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   vec4 texColor = texture2D( colorMap, varyingUV );\n"
    "   gl_FragColor = color * texColor;\n"
    "}"
#endif
}
};
```

The following code is for rendering.  I've looked at all the vars, _vertices, _blendFuncSource, etc and they are the same on iOS and OS X, so there is nothing odd going on there.  Is it correct to assume that this code should run on OpenGL ES and well as non-ES (Desktop)?

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture->glTexture());

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, _filter);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, _filter);

if (_useBlending) glEnable(GL_BLEND); else glDisable(GL_BLEND);

glBlendFunc(_blendFuncSource, _blendFuncDestination);

_shaderProgram->useProgram();

glUniformMatrix4fv(_shaderProgram->uniformModelViewProj, 1, 0, (GLfloat *)GGProjectTopMatrix());
glUniformMatrix4fv(_shaderProgram->uniformTextureMatrix, 1, 0, (GLfloat *)&IDENTITY_MATRIX);
glUniform1i(_shaderProgram->uniformColorMap, 0);

if (_premultAlpha)
    glUniform4fv(_shaderProgram->uniformColor, 1, (GLfloat *)&_colorPreMultipliedAlpha);
else
    glUniform4fv(_shaderProgram->uniformColor, 1, (GLfloat *)&_color);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, &_vertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, &_textureCoordinates);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

// Draw the vertices to the screen
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

glUseProgram(0);
```

The window and GL context is created using SDL on the desktop, but not on iOS. The Image (RGBA .png) is being loaded via SDL_Image (on the desktop) and everything seems to be correct.  If I display the image using SDL, it displays correctly, just not when I try and do everything through OpenGL.

When I draw simple triangles to the SDL OpenGL surface, they show up correctly (with my black textures on top), so I know pixels are being displayed.  Again, my images show up the correct size and in the right place, they are just a black square, so I assume it's some shader issue.  I can force the color in the fragment shader and the black images changes color.

Comment: What size are your textures? Without looking at the code in great detail, one thing that comes to mind is that support for non-power-of-2 textures was optional in OpenGL 2.0.

Comment: Ok, that wouldn't be the problem then. I'll take a closer look at your code tonight if it's not solved by then. Do you make sure that your `position` and `texcoord` attributes from the vertex shader are tied to attribute locations 0 and 1 by calling `glBindAttribLocation`?

Comment: I'm calling `glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "position"); glBindAttribLocation(program, 1, "texcoord");` when I compile the shaders.

Comment: Try using `gl_FragCoord.xy` for your texture coordinates just to rule out any issues with per-vertex data. If that still comes out black, then I suspect you have not bound your texture to the correct Texture Image Unit, or have some other texture setup issue.

Comment: I found it! I was passing the wrong format to `glTexImage2D`. Stupid typo in variable name!